# Override attribute from SharedAssemblyInfo in AssemblyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, assemblyinfo

In my solution there is SharedAssemblyInfo.cs that is integrated over a targets file (LinkedItems.targets).

[image: linkitems.targets]

[image: linkitems.targets.file]

In the SharedAssemblyInfo.cs there is a Version attribute set:

[image: SharedAssembyInfo]

I have some projects that have to define their own version. But this not possible in this case because then i get a duplicate "AssemblyVersion" Attribute error.

[image: duplicate assemblyversion attribute.]

Is there any way to resolve this issue besides defining the version in every single AssemblyInfo file and not in the SharedAssemblyInfo file?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. You can edit the ".targets" file that you use in your project file (you have to unload your project first).

[image]